# Jumbled Texture output when using D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE and Map/Unmap

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to change the data in a Texture2D with Map/Unmap and am running into an issue where the texture seems to only appear in the top 5th of the screen and the rest is just random pixels. [(screenshot for clarification)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43LU5.png)

Here's some code:

```
uint32_t* m_colorBuffer; //buffer to fill the texture with random colors
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA m_textureData;
ID3D11Texture2D* m_texture;
```

---

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
m_deviceContext->Map(m_texture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);

uint32_t rowSize = 256 * 4;
BYTE* mappedData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(mappedResource.pData);
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

    memcpy(mappedData, &(m_colorBuffer[i*rowSize]), rowSize);
    mappedData += mappedResource.RowPitch;
}

m_deviceContext->Unmap(m_texture, 0);
```

Can Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
I'd be happy to supply more code if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like my rowSize is in bytes and I'm using it to index m_colorBuffer.